# UITableview to always take full display height

Tags: ios, swift

is there a way in which a UITableView can always take a fixed height and can scale the static cells i'm using to the remaining height? I'm trying to achieve that my tableview layout is always visible on different devices.

Comment: I think you are trying to get a tableView to not be a tableView.  A UIStackView is designed to do exactly what you are describing.

Comment: but is a uistackview scrollable? just want to be as accessible as possible.

Comment: The way you describe in your question, it sounds like you always want everything on the screen, and you would resize to fit it, or to fill in all the space.  Perhaps your wording is why you didn't get the response you hoped for.

Comment: okay so i will try to use this approach and maybe get to ask a better question. But the mentioning of the Stackview was already helpful.

Comment: just closed the question now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you're getting at with having the table view showing on all devices. Instead of setting a specific size I'd recommend using auto layout instead! You can read more [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html).

Comment: So maybe I cant really describe what i'm trying to achieve. I already use auto sizing cells. But on Bigger devices the cells are a bit too small and only take the half of the screen whereas on an iphone 5 everything is fine. I just want the Cells to grow for the remaining free space.